# Unable to show popup of Date Picker in IE or Mozilla using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have included an input tag with date as its type in my html page. But the date picker is not popping up when the page loads. FYI, I'm creating an angularjs app.

```
Date Of Birth:<input type="date" ng-model="dob">
```

Comment: have you tried checking first the console in the browser's dev tool for some errors?

Comment: on firefox,chrome, and IE, try pressing `F12`..

Comment: Sorry what I mean to say was what changes (or settings) should I make in dev tools?

Comment: well, I was thinking that maybe the datepicker doesn't show because of some html errors, or maybe some js conflict.. If there are errors, it may appear on the console.. (if there are...) I suggest enabling the javascript on the dev tools

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. Ok,Can I expect any 3rd party date picker?

Comment: have you tried updating your browsers? and also I think `input` should end with `/>`